# Import CSV as float in a List (Python 3.5)

Tags: python, csv, import

I need to import a csv file, which contains about 1.000.000 numbers. they are all separated with decimals (,) so: 1,2,3,4,...

they just ordered easily in the file: no blanks no paragraphs.

This is my actual code:

```
import statistics
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    zahlenliste = list(reader)

print(zahlenliste)

# x = statistics.mean(zahlenliste)
# print(x)
```

I tried many codes, as on stackoverflow was presented, but I just couldn't execute it without any error.

with all the numbers in the list, i want the arithmetic mean as a result (which is actutally in commentary). with the print(zahlenliste) i wanted to look what the content of the list actually is and looks like:

```
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']]
```

would you be kind and help me just adding the right function to import the numbers as float to use it in the arithmetic.mean function?

Comment: It is much easier for us to see what is going wrong if you include the actual error message.

Comment: Welcome to SO :-)
Please look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for the edit Ulrich, @JETM: i know that it would be better, but as i am a beginner at importing files, i just tried few code snippets and tried to change them to my own code. so i just got a few different errors.

Comment: as i execute my actual code i get: 
File "...\wa\prog\listezahlen.py", line 11, in <module>
    x = statistics.mean(zahlenliste)
  File "...\\Python35-32\lib\statistics.py", line 293, in mean
    return _sum(data)/n
  File "...\\lib\statistics.py", line 162, in _sum
    n, d = exact_ratio(x)
  File "...\\lib\statistics.py", line 218, in _exact_ratio
    raise TypeError(msg.format(type(x).__name__)) from None
TypeError: can't convert type 'list' to numerator/denominator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items in your `zahlenliste` are characters, you'll need to cast them to numbers (`int` or `float`). A [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) comes in handy here:

```
zahlenliste = [[int(item) for item in line] for line in reader]
```

Now you've got a list of lists: The inner lists contain a line's values, the outer list represent the lines.
If you need to calculate the mean value for each line, use another list comprehension:

```
mittelwerte = [statistics.mean(line) for line in zahlenliste]
```

Comment: Thanks, but i get this error: float() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Comment: Of course, forgive me, I missed the nested statement. Should work by now

Comment: it works! great. but unfortunately i cant work further with the result. after using the arithmetic.mean it shows this error again: "can't convert type 'list' to numerator/denominator"